# restAssured - cannot master post method

Tags: java, automated-tests, kotlin, gmail-api, rest-assured

fellow stackoverflowians :)

I've been for quit time to make a Post call using Gmail API. 
Been trying to use createDraft and createLabel.
Now I guess I've found how to do this correctly (mostly) but I get this error:

```
    java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <400>.
```

I realise that this error occurs because I make incorrect request.

Could You, guys, help me with this? 
Here's my code:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured.*
import io.restassured.http.ContentType
import io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*
import org.testng.annotations.Test




class RestAPIAutoTestPost {
    @Test
    fun createLabelInGoogleMail() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me"
        val accessToken = "ya29.Glw7BEv6***"

        val jsonAsMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        jsonAsMap.put("id", "labelAPITestNameID")
        jsonAsMap.put("labelListVisibility", "labelShow")
        jsonAsMap.put("messageListVisibility", "show")
        jsonAsMap.put("messagesTotal", "0")
        jsonAsMap.put("messagesUnread", "0")
        jsonAsMap.put("name", "labelAPITestName")
        jsonAsMap.put("threadsTotal", "0")
        jsonAsMap.put("threadsUnread", "0")
        jsonAsMap.put("type", "user")


        given().
                contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                body(jsonAsMap).

        `when`()
                post("/labels?access_token=$accessToken").
        then().
                statusCode(200)
    }

}
```

I suppose I use HashMap incorrectly or I use some incorrect body fields. 
I've only started to learn **restAssured** so I beg my pardons for newby question.

Thanks!

P.S. I'd really appreciate for any help with **Post** methods and puting **data** into **body**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your use of RestAssured and HashMap is correct. I think you are getting a 400 from this API because you are specifying the `id` property. By playing with this in Google's API Explorer, I was able to generate 400 errors by doing that. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create), the only things you need to specify for a `POST/Create` are: `labelListVisibility`, `messageListVisibility`, and `name`. The `id` is returned to you as part of the response.

A good feature in RestAssured is that you can have it log what it sends or receives when there is an error or all the time.

Log all requests:

```
given().log().all()
```

Log all responses:

```
`when`().log().all()
```

Or just when validations fail:

```
`when`().log().ifValidationFails()
```

Using that will give you a more precise reason why your interaction with the API is failing because it will show whatever Google is sending back. So we can see for sure if I'm right about the `id`.

And since you seem to be using Kotlin for this, you might want to take advantage of its great multiline string capabilities and just create the JSON payload manually:

```
val body = """
    {
        "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
        "messageListVisibility": "show",
        "name": "ThisIsATest"
    }
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and for new things I learned :) 
 
But, you'll be laughing realy realy hard, my failure was because I forgot a goddamn **dot** after `when` statement :D This is the most stupid error I could ever make! I spend HOURS to fix this problem XD
 
Anyway, BIG THANKS to you for `log` and `kotlin json` feature!